# jQuery slidetoggle not working with full page slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slidetoggle

I have a page which uses full page slider. Also the top panel uses jQuery toggle. However, the same doesn't work when full page slider is used loading the content for it using AJAX. The url is http://goo.gl/o3Ow7

However, the same is working on individual slides. See http://goo.gl/pcfJm

Similarly the jQuery elastislide plugin is not working on last slide while it is working on the individual one. See goo.gl/UKRMF

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

apply this class on body: `single single-slide postid-42`

```
<body class="single single-slide postid-42" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
.....
</body>
```

Your current code is:

```
<body class="home blog" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
.....
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't worked. Also I see no relation to these class to the jQuery code as they are not used anywhere except the menu styling.